# How to programmatically click F5 in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

How to programmatically click F5 in Powerbuilder 12.5 using the send function. I have tried with this code but no luck.

```
Send(Handle(window),256,116,0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code from one of my apps:

```
Constant Long VK_F5 = 116
Constant UInt WM_KEYDOWN = 256
Constant UInt WM_KEYUP   = 257

Send(ll_handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0)
Send(ll_handle, WM_KEYUP, VK_F5, 0)
```

The difference seems to be that you aren't sending the keyup. Do you have code in the window's key event?